# How to load ConfigMap in Kustomize YAML file?

Tags: kubernetes

My original YAML

**base/deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: nginx
          name: nginx
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: database-configmap
data:
  config: |
    dbport=1234
    dcname=sfsdf
    dbssl=false
    locktime=300
    domainuser=
```

**base/Kustomization.yaml**

```
resources:
  - deployment.yaml

commonLabels:
  owner: sara
```

From the parent folder of base:

**`kustomize build base`**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
    owner: sara
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      owner: sara
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        owner: sara
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
```

If you observe above, the ConfigMap is being discarded, please suggest how to fix that.

Comment: I just tried and it's working fine on kustomize `v4.4.0`, which version are you using (`kustomize version` command)?

Comment: kustomize version
{Version:kustomize/v4.1.3 GitCommit:0f614e92f72f1b938a9171b964d90b197ca8fb68 BuildDate:2021-05-20T20:52:40Z GoOs:windows GoArch:amd64}

Comment: Just tried with `v4.1.3` and it's fine too....but two things to notice: on the output I have ConfigMap at the top, above the Deployoment. Maybe you missed it? The second one, I tried to use `Kustomization.yaml` name of file, but I got error `Error: unable to find one of 'kustomization.yaml', 'kustomization.yml' or 'Kustomization' in directory`. Please double check if you have a proper file name.

Comment: Don't know how, after restart of the machine, it is working. Can you please check this question also https://serverfault.com/questions/1079866/how-to-load-configmap-from-a-properties-file-using-kustomize

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both versions of the Kustomize - the current newest (`v.4.4.0`) and `v4.1.3` used in the question it is working correctly. The author notice that the restart can help:

> after restart of the machine, it is working.

Keep in mind about two things:

- `base/Kustomization.yaml` name can't be used; you will get an error `Error: unable to find one of 'kustomization.yaml', 'kustomization.yml' or 'Kustomization' in directory`. There is a need to use proper name.
- After running command: `kustomize build base` the ConfigMap will be generated at the top of the output, even if it is defined at the bottom in the resource file. Check below.

Output of the `kustomize build base` command:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |
    dbport=1234
    dcname=sfsdf
    dbssl=false
    locktime=300
    domainuser=
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    owner: sara
  name: database-configmap
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
    owner: sara
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      owner: sara
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        owner: sara
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
```

Comment: can you check this also https://serverfault.com/questions/1079866/how-to-load-configmap-from-a-properties-file-using-kustomize