# How to load configmap from a properties file using kustomize?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have tried using kustomize to load properties file as a configmap.

For that, I created a sample set as in github [link](https://github.com/sarajune/Kustomize_YAML).

With base files:

```
#kustomize build base
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: |-
    dbport=1234
    dcname=sfsdf
    dbssl=false
    locktime=300
    domainuser=
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    owner: sara
  name: database-configmap
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
    owner: sara
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      owner: sara
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        owner: sara
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
```

With external file:

```
#kustomize build file
apiVersion: v1
data:
  config: "dbport=156767\r\ndcname=dfsd\r\ndbssl=false\r\nlocktime=300\r\ndomainuser=somedts"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    env: dev
    owner: sara
  name: dev-database-configmap
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
    env: dev
    owner: sara
  name: dev-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
      env: dev
      owner: sara
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
        env: dev
        owner: sara
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
```

If you observe the configmap `|` is removed and also replaced by `\r\n` as a single string.
How to fix this alignment?

Comment: Well, the `\r` characters aside, those two forms are identical; the `: |` scalar quoting for is just for human consumption -- by the time it gets into the cluster it is of the form `config: "whatever\nwhatever-else\n"` as `yaml2json` will show for both forms, or, of course, how it actually materializes in a Pod

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this as community wiki, feel free to edit and expand.

---

As @mdaniel mentioned in [comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/1079866/how-to-load-configmap-from-a-properties-file-using-kustomize#comment1409739_1079866):

> Well, the \r characters aside, those two forms are identical; the : |
> scalar quoting for is just for human consumption -- by the time it
> gets into the cluster it is of the form config:
> "whatever\nwhatever-else\n" as yaml2json will show for both forms, or,
> of course, how it actually materializes in a Pod

You can check this by getting the configmap details from kubernetes cluster in `json` and see that they are stored in the same way (except for additional `\r` which is mentioned above):

```
$ kubectl get cm database-configmap -o json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "config": "dbport=1234\ndcname=sfsdf\ndbssl=false\nlocktime=300\ndomainuser="
    },
    "kind": "ConfigMap",
    ...
```

and

```
$ kubectl get cm dev-database-configmap -o json
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "data": {
        "config": "dbport=156767\r\ndcname=dfsd\r\ndbssl=false\r\nlocktime=300\r\ndomainuser=somedts"
    },
    "kind": "ConfigMap",
    ...
```

---

There's an answer on StackOverflow which shortly shows the [difference between \n , \r and \r\n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15433263/15537201).

Comment: Hello @SaraJune. Does this [answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?